# How to show Items in a category from Wordpress post and page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress CMS. I Creat Post and page for particular Category. I want to send the post and page item through respective Category. And also I want to control the number of showing post in category. How can I send the post and page item in category. I have attach bellow normal coding. Plz help me.

```
    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post();?>

                </div>
            <div class="category-page">
                <div class="cate-inn ">
                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"> <?php 

the_title();?></a></h2>

                        <div class="cat-image fix">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"> <?php 
the_post_thumbnail();?></a>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function in WP that should help you with that.
You can find info on it here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

I have a ready to go snippet here to help you
https://snippetbox.xyz/5c3db100112bca204644/