# How do i get Custum Post Type Category items Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

my code is to get all portfolio items but I want only one category item.

These are my category.
http://prntscr.com/mzzjfy

Thanks and sorry for my bad language.

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'dt_portfolio',
  'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page' => '50',

);
$rhy_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($rhy_query->have_posts()): $rhy_query->the_post();


the_title();

endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010436/how-to-show-items-in-a-category-from-wordpress-post-and-page

Comment: I try it but not working :/

Comment: Can you share more information in order to know a little bit more? Have you check the correct creation of the custom post type¿?

Comment: This theme is the7